# Make field of a class optional for json conversion

Tags: java, json, class, jackson, field

I have a spring-boot application. I have exposed an API that consumes JSON body.
Payload looks like this:

```
{ userName: Karan,
userId: 123,
age: 29,
addtionalInfo: {accountType: A}

}
```

My method has a corresponding class to handle this payload:

```
class PayloadDto {
private String userName;
private String userId;
private int age;
private Map<String, String> addtionalInfo;

public PayloadDto(){}

//getters
//setters
}
```

This works fine.

Recently, we have to make an enhancement in our api. Now, I have to enhance the class to accept 2 types of payloads. one mentioned above should work fine as it is and enhanced class should also work fine for below new payload:

```
{ userName: Karan,
userId: 123,
age: 29,
addtionalInfo: {accountType: A}
occupationDetails : { designation: developer, email: abc@xyz.com, companyName: Alfa}

}
```

Can you help what should my class look like so that it works fine for both of these 2 json payloads?

I thought of writing class like this:

```
class PayloadDto {
private String userName;
private String userId;
private int age;
private Map<String, String> addtionalInfo;
private Map<String, String> occupationDetails;
public PayloadDto(){}

//getters
//setters
}
```

But this will work fine only with 2nd json and fail for 1st json payload.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume your JSON is actually valid and looks like this:

```
{
  "userName": "Karan",
  "userId": 123,
  "age": 29,
  "addtionalInfo": {
    "accountType": "A"
  },
  "occupationDetails": {
    "designation": "developer",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com",
    "companyName": "Alfa"
  }
}
```

Then your class would be:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
class PayloadDto {
  private String userName;
  private String userId;
  private int age;

  // new data types
  private AdditionalInfo additionalInfo;
  private OccupationDetails occupationDetails;

  public PayloadDto(){}

  //getters
  //setters
}
```

So basically you just create new classes and define their corresponding members, just like you did with the "base" class.

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` tells Jackson to ignore absent (your "optional") properties.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my json. I just want my single API method to work for 2 different types of payloads as mentioned above (2 jsons above: one has "occupationDetails" while other doesnt). So, if any one of the above json payload is passed in api call, my method should work fine.

My api method looks like this:
       
@PutMapping(value = "/v1, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public String addUser(@RequestBody PayloadDataDTO payload) {   .                          
    //Do Something with the payload received 
}

Comment: I just only added @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) over my PayloadDataDTO class. To my surprise, actually my PayloadDataDto class is able to handle both payloads. I am not sure but now i think even without any annotation also, it would work fine. So, definitely, I dont have to use: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)

Comment: so what exactly is your problem, does your code work now? Using the approach I described you should be able to handle both payloads. `additionalInfo` and `occupationDetails` will be null if they are missing from the payload.

Comment: Hey, I just didnt know that all class fields are required=false by default. Hence, A simple addtion of new field "private OccupationDetails occupationDetails;" in the class works out for me. I know how to use NonNull, NonEmpty etc further. I just wanted the class not to break for both calls with 2 different payloads mentioned by me. Thanks anyways.
"